# Behavior of cuts in negation

Tags: prolog, iso-prolog

The following code, as expected, outputs `123` because of backtracking:

```
between(1,3,X), write(X), false.
```

This one with the cut outputs `1`, also as expected:

```
between(1,3,X), write(X), !, false.
```

But this one outputs `123` surprisingly:

```
between(1,3,X), write(X), not(!).
```

`not(!)` evaluates to false so in one way it makes sense that it backtracks but at the same time it should have cut and therefore have no other possibilites to explore.

The same behaviour happens with `\+` instead of `not/1`.

Why is the cut not having any side effect when negated? For example `write/1` in a `not` has the same side effect as when it's not in one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[(\+)/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=%5C%2B/1) it's a metacall builtin, and (citing the [!/0](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=!/0) docs)

> Meta calling is opaque to the cut.

The examples, specially t4, illustrate the operational semantic

Comment: Sorry, but example t4 is **incorrect**. There is no predicate `(\+)/3`.

Comment: Contrary to the documentation of SWI, `(\+)/1` is handled (incorrectly) like a control construct - so it is not handled like a built-in. As an example, consider: `call((fail,\+1))` which must fail, but in SWI it is an error. This is non-conforming behavior specific to SWI.